# How do I find the users biggest donation? without aggregate functions

Tags: mysql

For example given

table1

```
userId donation
1      50
1      150
1      340
1      20
2      85
2      15
```

I want

```
userId donation
1      340
2      85
```

I thought about cross joining them and see which was bigger but don't know what to do after this

```
SELECT * FROM 
table1 as T1 cross join table1 as T2
WHERE
T1.userId = T2.userId
and
T1.donation > T2.donation
```

Comment: Use ORDER BY to donation column by descending way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select *
from table1 T1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table1 T2
    where T2.userId=T1.userId and T2.donation > T1.donation
)
```

or the equivalent join:

```
select *
from table1 T1
left join table1 T2 on T2.userId=T1.userId and T2.donation > T1.donation
where T2.userId is null
```

If there are two rows with the same donation, both of them will be selected.  If you don't want that, also compare primary key columns or some other unique keys:

```
T2.userId=T1.userId and (T2.donation,T2.primarykeycol1,T2.primarykeycol2) > (T1.donation,T1.primarykeycol1,T1.primarykeycol2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join and then compare the highest donation with the records of secondary table but same user.

```
SELECT T1.userId, T1.donation
FROM table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN table1 T2 ON T1.userId = T2.userId AND T1.donation < T2.donation
WHERE T2.id IS NULL;
```

***MySQL 8***

```
WITH s1 AS (
   SELECT userId, 
       donation,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY donation DESC) AS `Rank`
   FROM table1 
)
SELECT s1.userId, s1.donation
FROM s1
WHERE s1.`Rank` = 1;
```